# Using Hardware layer for android WebView will drain battery too much?

Tags: android, android-webview

On some stack overflow threads I found that using hardware layer for android WebView will increase its performance. So currently I am using hardware layer for WebView.
But one of the user of my app is complaining about draining battery too much fast. Will hardware layer impacts battery performance? If yes, then we have to use it or not for android WebView? If we should't use it, then what about WebView performance? Will performance degrade?

Comment: Too many unknowns from what does you app do or perhaps is the user on a old phone and needs a new battery. If there are concerns see: [Analyze power use with Battery Historian](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/battery-historian)

Comment: My app is a browser which uses android WebView to render webpages. But yes, there may be a possibility of a user using old phone. Because I have 4000 activce users and no one is complaining except a one user.